# Missing Child While Using lxml to Parse Children of Paragraph Tag

Tags: python, html, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I am using the Python library [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) to perform XML parsing on the HTML retrieved from [this url](http://ohhla.com/YFA_natedogg.html). I have had no trouble using lxml in the past, however I may have just encountered a bug in the form of a missing child element (in the lxml tree) which plainly appears in the HTML.

Here is the Python code I am using to parse the HTML:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

html_response = urlopen("http://ohhla.com/YFA_natedogg.html")
html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(html_response, html_parser)
tree.xpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber7']/tr[2]/td/p[1]")[0]
```

A simplified version of the HTML code from the website I am parsing looks like this:

```
<table id='AutoNumber7'>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                # ... (irrelevant tags) ... 
                <p>
                    <a></a>
                    # The following <table> tag is what I need to target:
                    <table></table>
                </p>
                # ... (seven <p> tags identical to the above) ...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

When I run `tree.xpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber7']/tr[2]/td/p[1]")[0].getchildren()`
 in the console, lxml only detects the initial anchor tag `<a>` and ignores the sibling `<table>` tag that I need to select (denoted by the above comment in the code).

Here is the console output:

```
tree.xpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber7']/tr[2]/td/p[1]")[0].getchildren()
Out[22]: [<Element a at 0x2904a2a5808>]
```

What I expect to see is:

```
tree.xpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber7']/tr[2]/td/p[1]")[0].getchildren()
Out[22]: [<Element a at 0x2904a2a5808>, <Element table at 0x???????????>]
```

Any ideas why the `<table>` tag is missing from the `<p>` tag's children?
How can I select this `<table>` tag? I need to parse all content from the table tag, but lxml seems to not recognize it as a valid child element. If anyone can provide a working xpath selector for the desired `<table>` tag I would be very greatful!

Note: I understand that I should really be seeing `[<Element tr at 0x??????????>, <Element tr at 0x???????????>, ...]` not `[<Element table at 0x??????????>]` but I was trying to be more concise.

EDIT: For those who don't consider the above code reproducible, literally just copy and paste this into the console:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

html_response = urlopen("http://ohhla.com/YFA_natedogg.html")
html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(html_response, html_parser)
print(tree.xpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber7']/tr[2]/td/p[1]")[0].getchildren())
```

As before the HTML I am trying to parse is located [here](http://ohhla.com/YFA_natedogg.html).

I don't really know how to be more concise than this. Constructive comments are appreciated (as always).

- Linking to pages I have already read (e.g. [How to create a Minimal,
  Complete, and Verifiable
  example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) **without commentary**
  is not constructive criticism.
- Pointing out what steps I may have missed, or what to improve upon in the future (from a particular resource) is constructive criticism that is beneficial to both myself and the community as a whole.
- I gladly accept advice on how to improve my posts, but please provide actual recommendations. Remember that several people may read the same resource and come to separate conclusions.

Comment: "*Here is the Python code I am using to parse the HTML*" - No, I don't think that is the Python code you are using. Specifically `tree` is never defined. Please copy-paste, never re-type, the exact short program you are using. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for pointing that out, the code was not re-typed. I simply missed copying that line of code. The code was scattered over a large method, so I had to copy only the relevant lines that would re-produce the issue detailed above.

Comment: Where's `tbody` in your XPath?  And given that it's missing, why are you seeing an `a` element in the console as you claim to be?

Comment: @kjhughes For some reason (unbeknown to me) the xpath selector doesn't work when `<tbody>` is included. If you run the code: `tree.xpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber7']/tr[2]/td/p[1]")[0].getchildren()` as is, you should see the same console output I am receiving.

Comment: The actual HTML, unlike what you've posted, has no `tbody`.  Go back and create a real ***[mcve]*** and stop wasting everyone's time.  Your question should stand on its own -- not rely on any external links -- so that it'll be of value to future readers.  The problem should also be **verifiable** based on just what's in your question.

Comment: @kjhughes Thank you for the constructive feedback! I will repost the question without relying on external links. This is feedback I can actually use to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that lxml tries to play by the rules of HTML. According to those rules, `<table>` (a block level element) cannot be a child of `<p>`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1.

Short demo:

```
from lxml import html

test = """
<html>
  <p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>XXX</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p>
</html>"""

root = html.fromstring(test)

# Just print the string representation of the parsed HTML
print(html.tostring(root).decode("UTF-8"))
```

In the output from this code we can see that lxml refuses to interpret `<table>` as a child of `<p>`:

```
<html>
  <body><p>
    </p><table>
      <tr>
        <td>XXX</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</body></html>
```

`<a>` is an inline element so it makes sense that it is included in the return value from `getchildren()`. You will have to find some other way to identify the `<table>` elements that you are interested in.

The http://ohhla.com/YFA_natedogg.html document claims to be XHTML, but it has many errors and it cannot be parsed as an XML document.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I feared. I appreciate your concise and easy to understand example (unlike mine).  Do you have any suggestions for how to select the `<table>` element that is a child of a `<p>` tag in Python? Should I just abandon xpath selectors entirely for this purpose?

Comment: I think it should work if you look for following-siblings of `<p>` rather than children.