# Why is lxml closing this "ol" tag when parsing?

Tags: html-parsing, lxml

Here is some HTML:

```
<ol><ul><li>item</li></ul></ol>
```

and some python 3 code with `lxml` to parse it and re-print it:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree, html

document_root = html.fromstring(sys.stdin.read())
print(etree.tostring(document_root, encoding='unicode'))
```

Here is the output:

```
<div><ol/><ul><li>item</li></ul>
</div>
```

In the output, `lxml` closes the `ol` before the `ul` starts, which changes the list structure.

Why is it doing that?

**Can I get `lxml` to parse HTML in such a way as to preserve the list structure?**

**EDIT**: NOTE that this example parses fine if I replace `ul` with `ol` (`<ol><ol><li>item</li></ol></ol>`), or if I replace `ol` with `ul` (`<ul><ul><li>item</li></ul></ul>`).  The output is unchanged from the input.

I don't have control over the HTML, it could come from anywhere.

I'm using lxml 4.6.3, installed from PyPi, and python 3.9.

OR, is there another way to parse HTML in a way that I can pull list text out of it preserving the list structure in Python?

Just so you know, I'm using lxml to drop attributes, so below is code that is closer to my use case.  However, I wanted to give the smallest reproducible test case first.

Code closer to my use case:

```
import sys

import lxml.html.clean as clean
from lxml import etree, html

document_root = html.fromstring(sys.stdin.read())

cleaner = clean.Cleaner(safe_attrs_only=True, safe_attrs=frozenset())
cleansed = cleaner.clean_html(document_root)

# Do something with the lists in cleansed, defined by ol, ul, and li ..

print(etree.tostring(cleansed, encoding='unicode')
```

Comment: Can't explain why, but it seems to be a problem only with `html`. It seems to work with `document_root = etree.fromstring(sys.stdin.read())`.

Comment: Maybe that is a thing for me to try. I thought html would be more resilient to html fragments from the world that may not be so well formed, but maybe the bigger threat is lxml breaking well formed html.

Comment: "maybe the bigger threat is lxml breaking well formed html" - yes, it's bothering me as well; don't recall ever encountering that and it's worrisome. Let's hope one of lxml's Powers that Be notices this and addresses the issue.

Comment: I think neither HTML 4 nor HTML5 allows an `ul` element as a child of an `ol` element, that might be part of the reason why an HTML parser builds a tree structure not representing the nesting you have in your input markup. Whether a "traditional" HTML 4 parser, like probably implemented in lxml's/libxml's HTML parser algorithm did the same change to the structure is something I don't remember and I am not sure where to test it. While two HTML5 validators clearly flag your `ul` as a not allowed child of `ol` the current browsers seem to preserve that nesting.

Comment: I also think the problem is `ul` as a child of `ol`. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44976672/407651.

Comment: @mzjn Ah, this makes sense. From the other answer, ol should have only li elements as children. The issue is that I encounter this html in the wild, and wish to parse it as if it were legal. Note that for example chrome displays it as a nested list, so likely that encourages people to use it that way. Simplest way to parse this as nested?

Comment: Your sample HTML is well-formed XML, so it can be parsed as XML. But you cannot rely on that if you work with arbitrary HTML "in the wild".

Comment: @mzjn Agreed. So any thoughts on how to robustly parse HTML "in the wild" in a way more similar to how browsers do it? Not in general, just to parse out lists like this.

Comment: @mzjn If you submit this answer ("not valid HTML") I'll accept it, as it answers the question. I can ask another question about parsing the HTML I'm getting.

Comment: Btw, perhaps you can use Selenium WebDriver (it has a Python API), or some other browser automation tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235395/discussion-between-dfrankow-and-mzjn).

Comment: @MartinHonnen If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think neither HTML 4 nor HTML5 allows an `ul` element as a child of an `ol` element.  Only `li` elements can be direct children.

That might be why an HTML parser builds a tree structure not representing the nesting you have in your input markup. Whether a "traditional" HTML 4 parser, like probably implemented in lxml's/libxml's HTML parser algorithm, did the same change to the structure is something I don't remember and I am not sure where to test it.

While two HTML5 validators flag your `ul` as a not-allowed child of `ol`, current browsers seem to preserve that nesting.