# Can I safely replace "<ul>" tags within HTML using regexes?

Tags: html, regex, lxml

I am trying to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68536635), where users paste invalid HTML that we have to deal with, of the form `<ol><ul><li>item</li></ul></ol>`.  We are currently parsing using `lxml`.  In legal HTML, `<ol>` cannot have a (direct) child of a `<ul>` (it must be in an `<li>`) so `lxml` closes the `ol` tag too soon to try to "repair" the HTML, producing `<div><ol/><ul><li>item</li></ul>`.

The user-pasted text also might be invalid XML (e.g., bare `<br>` tag), so we can't just parse it as XML.

Thus, we can neither parse it as HTML nor XML, because it might be invalid.

To make this certain (common) case of invalid HTML into valid HTML, **can we just replace all `<ul>` tags with `<ol>` tags using regexes?**

If I use lxml to parse `<ol><ol><li>item</li></ol></ol>`, the output looks fine (does not close a tag too soon).

However, I don't want to break actual user-typed text, and I'm wondering if there are edge cases I haven't thought of (like "`<ul>`" within a `<pre>` tag or some other crazy thing that isn't actually a tag, though I've tested that particular case).

Yes, it would change unnumbered lists to numbered lists. I'm okay with that.

Yes, I have read [this fun regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Comment: You can't have `<ol>` as a direct child of `<ol>`, for the same reason.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Browsers do similar things when they receive invalid HTML.

Comment: Unless you know all the types of erroneous HTML people will paste, you're not going to be able to solve this in a general, robust manner. `lxml` is already making its best attempt to resolve the errors, what makes you think your fix-ups will be any better?

Comment: For clarity, `<ol><ol><li>item</li></ol></ol>` "looks fine" = unaffected / nested-ol output (??), while `<ol><ul><li>item</li></ul></ol>` "closes the first ol before the ul"? Or did I misread that..

Comment: Anyway, some cases where a direct replacement might *invalidly* alter the HTML - inside HTML comments, inside script elements, *inside attribute values*. There may be more contexts.

Comment: @Barmar "Garbage in, garbage out. Browsers do similar things when they receive invalid HTML." Every browser I have tested has rendered an ol with nested ul (and no intermediate li) the way you'd expect, by acting as if an li were there. So, while I agree with "garbage in garbage out" for computer-to-computer communication, for human-to-computer, we will be forced to deal with things the way browsers do. Our fixups will be better if we can tolerate invalid HTML the way a browser does. lxml does not appear to be doing that well.

Comment: @user2864740 You read correctly. And, if you submit your comment ("some cases.."), I will accept it as an answer. Unfortunately not the answer I want, but an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no guarantee of a 'non-edge case' transform with HTML and regular expressions. HTML, more so than XML, has rules that make a direct text replacement of things that look like tags problematic.

The following text [validates as HTML using w3c.org validation checker](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) without any warnings.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title><!--<ul>--></title>
  <style lang="css">s {content: "<ul>";}</style>
  <script>"<ul>"</script>
</head>
<body data-ul="<ul>"></body>
</html>
```

That aside, using some regular expression heuristics might solve the issue at hand - at least insofar as a reasonable scope. A streaming HTML token parser that does not attempt to apply any validation or DOM/tree building might also be useful for the initial replacement stage.