# How do I parse HTML lists in python like browsers do, tolerating lack of li elements?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm taking HTML from user cut-and-paste (in a [Summernote rich edit](https://summernote.org/) widget).  That means it doesn't have to be valid HTML or valid XML, and I cannot control that.  Here is an example that is both invalid HTML (`ul` is a child of `ol`, instead of having an `li` element as a child) and invalid XML (unclosed `br` tag).

```
<ol>one<ul>two<li>item</li></ul><br></ol>
```

Chrome and safari both render this as if "two" is in a nested list, even without the li:

[image]

That seems reasonable.

However, [parsing in python using `lxml` does not return an equivalent list structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536635/why-is-lxml-closing-this-ol-tag-when-parsing). See that question, it returns:

```
<div><ol/><ul><li>item</li></ul>
</div>
```

I need to accept malformed HTML and XML and repair it in such a way as the list structure in particular is preserved the way browsers display it.  More precisely, in this particular case (missing `li`), if a browser would choose to display an item as nested, I want to parse it out as nested.

Suggestions for how to do that?  Are there python HTML parsers that can handle this particular case more robustly?

[Regexes are not great for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658461/can-i-safely-replace-ul-tags-within-html-using-regexes).

However I phrase this question, people seem to give answers of the form, "You should really have well-formed HTML/XML", but that is not a useful answer here.  I don't control it.  I need to handle malformed HTML/XML, for this one malformation (missing `li`), because browsers handle it.

Comment: You are looking for a predictable answer to an unpredictable question.  That sequence is not valid HTML, so there is no "right answer".  Just because Chrome and Safari happen to render it that way today does not mean that other browsers will, or even that THEY will in their next release.  You're trying to extract order from chaos.  If anything, the right answer should be to flag this as invalid HTML.

Comment: Somehow this voice always comes up, even though I explicitly mentioned it in the question. Sure, I can flag it, but users don't care. They copied something from somewhere, it looked fine, now they want it to work. If it changes in future, they will want that to work. Yes, making a joyful product to use is exactly extracting order from chaos.

Comment: I suppose it's a philosophical thing.  These users are making a mistake.  They have broken code.  Someone needs to tell them how to do it correctly.  Why not you?  Isn't that better for society then trying to emulate unpredictable behavior?

Comment: No. They probably don't own the code that is broken (e.g., microsoft word, google docs, notion, etc.). Anyway, that is no way to run a business. "You've made a mistake, but you don't know it because everything looks fine, and every browser in the world renders it correctly. Please go and change some code you don't have access to instead of getting your job done with our tool" is the wrong answer.

Comment: Well, I disagree categorically, but it's your client.

Comment: It is not one client. If we make a tool public, it could be hundreds or thousands of clients. We might not even ever meet the users of our tool directly.

Comment: Did the answer not help?

Comment: The answer looks very helpful, thank you. I have not had an opportunity to try it yet. I will vote when I give it a try.

Comment: Have you never found an opportunity to try the answer?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sadly true. This was at the top of my list for days, then by the time I finally got an answer (this was not the first stack overflow question), it had dropped off my list, where it stays. I still have to address it, but there are a dozen things above it. :/

Answer (score 1):

There is `html5lib` for Python so

```
import html5lib

def print_tree(node, indent = ''):
    print(indent + node.tag)
    for n in node:
        print_tree(n, indent = indent + '\t')

document = html5lib.parse("<ol>one<ul>two<li>item</li></ul><br></ol>")
print(html5lib.serialize(document))

print_tree(document)
```

gives e.g.

```
<ol>one<ul>two<li>item</ul><br></ol>
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html
        {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}head
        {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body
                {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}ol
                        {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}ul
                                {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li
                        {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}br
```

meaning, a tree similar to the browser's DOM tree https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/saved/9540 is built.

If you don't want the HTML namespace in the tree use `document = html5lib.parse("<ol>one<ul>two<li>item</li></ul><br></ol>", namespaceHTMLElements = False)`.

You can also use html5lib to build an lxml tree:

```
import html5lib

def print_tree(node, indent = ''):
    print(indent, node.tag, node.text if node.text else '')
    for n in node:
        print_tree(n, indent = indent + '\t')

document = html5lib.parse("<ol>one<ul>two<li>item</li></ul><br></ol>", treebuilder = 'lxml', namespaceHTMLElements = False)

print_tree(document.getroot())
```